# Building packages npm workspaces

Tags: node.js, npm, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I'm using npm workspaces. There is a need to build each project separately

`npm ci` - will install dependencies for all packages + root dependencies
`npm ci -w @project/foo` will only install dependencies for the selected package
How do I now put dependencies on the root package.json only? 
Without it, nothing wants to start because there are common dependencies
I found `npm ci --workspaces=false`, but if you install package dependencies after or before, they will be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```bash
npm ci -w @project/foo/brain -include-workspace-root
```